# change my code from cereal to air quality

Tags: user-interface, shinydashboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyzn9.png)I copied the exercise code but it is for cereal, how do I change it to show air quality? I will attach a picture for reference from the book rstudio for dummies. I try inputting the data set but it throws off my app.

```
 library(shinydashboard)
library(MASS)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Brushing"),
    dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            plotOutput("CerealPlot",
                       click = "single_click",
                       hover = "hovering",
                       brush = "brushing")
        ),
        box((verbatimTextOutput("coords")), width = 8)
    )
)
head(airquality)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$CerealPlot <- renderPlot({
        plot(x=UScereal$protein, y=UScereal$calories,
             xlab="Protein(gm)",
             ylab="Calories",
             pch=as.character(UScereal$mfr)) 
        })
    output$coords <- renderPrint({
        nearPoints(UScereal, input$single_click,
                   xvar = "protein", yvar = "calories", threshold=20)
        
    }) 
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it throws off my app_? What don't you like in the displayed dashboard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.